# Tab Active Across Multiple Pages Without Page Refresh

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

If I'm going between multiple pages, how can I get the a tab to stay open/active on each subsequent page?

Example, on the landing page, I click the tab for "English" and then what I click a link for "Products" the tab for English is already open on the Product page.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="langTab">
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#español" aria-controls="español" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Español</a></li>
<li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#english" aria-controls="english" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">English</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="español" role="tabpanel">Spanish content</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="english" role="tabpanel">English content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can try to use localstorage to save the current tab. And pick up this value when open new page and or when page is get focused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add event listener on your tab-click and than you can save tab id in the localstorage, something like that

```
<a href="#español" aria-controls="español" onclick="tabClicked()" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Español</a>
```

and js

```
function tabClicked() {
   localStorage.setItem('active-tab', $(event.currentTarget).attr('href'));
}
```

and then on your `window.onload` AND `window.onfocus` events you put this

```
var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('active-tab');
// and trigger that tab
if (activeTab) {
    $('[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
```